# How can I address specific XML-Elements with C# when using namespaces?

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces

I have to import XML-documents into a SQL-DB via C#. The XML has several namespaces.

I tried to address the specific elements I want wo import via XPath, but it broke due to the namespaces. Instead of

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc = XDocument.Load(Filename);
GENERATOR_INFO = doc.SelectSingleNode("ORDER/ORDER_HEADER/ORDER_INFO/GENERATOR_INFO").InnerText;
```

I write something like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc = XDocument.Load(Filename);
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("openTrans", "http://www.opentrans.org/XMLSchema/2.1");
GENERATOR_INFO = doc.SelectSingleNode("//openTrans:GENERATOR_INFO", nsmgr).InnerText;
```

thus shortening the "path" to the element I need the Value of.

My question is: How can I address an element directly? In the XMl there are two elements called "ORDER_ID":

```
ORDER/ORDER_HEADER/ORDER_INFO/ORDER_ID
```

and

```
ORDER/ORDER_HEADER/CUSTOMER_ORDER_REFERENCE/ORDER_INFO
```

When using the syntax above I get only one element, with a loop/Linq I get both values but don't know, which one is which.
Is there an option to address the elements by there unique XPath despite the namespace?

regards

Jens

Comment: Found it :)

I have to reference every "step" of the XPath:
    
    ORDER_ID = doc.SelectSingleNode("//openTrans:ORDER_INFO/openTrans:ORDER_ID", nsmgr).InnerText;

resp.

    VIND_ORDER_ID = COR.SelectSingleNode("//openTrans:CUSTOMER_ORDER_REFERENCE/openTrans:ORDER_ID", nsmgr).InnerText

Comment: You should post your comment as the answer, as allowed by the FAQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it :) 
I have to reference every "step" of the XPath: ORDER_ID = doc.SelectSingleNode("//openTrans:ORDER_INFO/openTrans:ORDER‌​_ID", nsmgr).InnerText; resp. VIND_ORDER_ID = COR.SelectSingleNode("//openTrans:CUSTOMER_ORDER_REFERENCE/o‌​penTrans:ORDER_ID", nsmgr).InnerText